# Can I extract the type of an observable in a mapped type?

Tags: typescript

I have this interface:

```
export interface MainEvents {
  successful$: Observable<EventObject>;
  notSuccessful$: Observable<EventObject>;
  ended$: Observable<EventObject>;
}
```

I want to make a type that uses the same keys but instead of `Observable<EventObject>` it should be `BehaviorSubject<EventObject>`

I have defined my type:

```
 type SubjectsType = {
   [P in keyof MainEvents ]: BehaviorSubject<MainEvents [P]>; 
 }
```

But of course it declares it as `BehaviorSubject<Obserbable<EventObject>>` instead of `BehaviorSubject<EventObject>`

Is there a way to automatically extract the type Type so eventually I can add more interface members with different observable types or Do I need to do it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to extract the generic type paramter in combination with `infer`:

```js
type SubjectsType = {
    [P in keyof MainEvents]: BehaviorSubject<MainEvents[P] extends Observable<infer X> ? X : never>;
}
```

This will now result in the generic type paramter as value, or `never` if the value is not of type `Observable` to begin with.

You can also see this in action in [this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMDO0Bud0A2EAPACoB8yA3gL4BQoksiKAQhABZw7AD2UAZQCu6AFYQEYMpVp05jaPCTIAojgjgM4ydXp0IADwAO-MMgXNlAWTig1GsJmp1kyTEIRJMmGEIIASAC40LFx8ImJ7TTEJMHIAbhdkEF4wYU8Ib18A4IxsKDxCEiiwLViEpI0AEwgqoJD8woiSsskK1xheXnq8sKLiECEAW3RoCr0wAE8jFGEYyUxSaZQAXmdXVwBtAAVzEGQAawhJ3hhkGzt1cEwAXWD2Lh5+Oe0pC5ASzB2b5ENIECqTl6BXCJFAMGgyAAGpQAPzQ5DBEAQdRQBLIOh6IA).

You can also make `SubjectType` generic and thus allowing reuse:

```js
type SubjectsType<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: BehaviorSubject<T[P] extends Observable<infer X> ? X : never>; 
}

type MainSubjectTypes = SubjectsType<MainEvents>;
```